# Unable to establish connection to bitcoin using json and php

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, json-rpc, php

I'm newbie to bitcoins. Im trying to get the info, as much as I can.
I'm trying to get the information by using `getinfo()` method that is mention in api documentation.
The code i have tried is mentioned below.

```
   require_once('jsonRPCClient.php');
        $bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://identifier:identiferpass@rpc.blockchain.info:443'); 
 print_r($bitcoin->getinfo());
```

I have googled it but didn't find the solution. I'm not getting what is the issue in the above code.

I just want to create a hello world connection. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you get an error, or just nothing at all? Is the `jsonRPCClient.php` in the right directory?

Comment: yes it is in right directory.

Comment: the error is : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to connect to https://identfier:password@rpc.blockchain.info:443 Error: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl' in D:\wamp\www\bitcoin\jsonRPCClient.php on line 231

Comment: and one more : RuntimeException: Unable to connect to https://identifier:identifierpasswrd@rpc.blockchain.info:443 Error: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl in D:\wamp\www\bitcoin\jsonRPCClient.php on line 231

Comment: So it looks like you cant make a connection at all. I found [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro) site, shouldnt you make an account with password?

Comment: come again please. there is a password....

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to http over the https port.

For HTTP use:

> $bitcoin = new
>   jsonRPCClient('[http://identifier:identiferpass@rpc.blockchain.info](http://identifier%3aidentiferpass@rpc.blockchain.info)');

For HTTPS use:

> $bitcoin = new
>   jsonRPCClient('[https://identifier:identiferpass@rpc.blockchain.info](https://identifier%3aidentiferpass@rpc.blockchain.info)');

According to the blockchain.info documentation both should work.

Answer (score 1):

The error it is giving you tells you that you need a version of libCURL with SSL support. Download the latest version with SSL support from below, open the Zip archive, go in to the "dlls" folder and replace the DLLs in your PHP installation with the new ones. Make sure you download the one which matches the architecture of your PHP installation, not the OS. For instance if you're running the 32 bit version of PHP on a 64 bit version of Windows, you'd want the 32 bit version of libCURL with SSL support.

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

You might need to restart IIS (or whatever web server you're using) after you replace the DLLs.